# Load data from different sources

Tags: php, jquery

I want to load a page from a different source like how the online flight ticket reservation sites are working. Meaning the data needs to be pulled from different systems and show it up in a single page.

I can do this by creating one file which can collects the data from different systems and merge it by the required sort order and show in the page. But if any one of the source systems works slow then the entire page needs to wait till all the results are received from various sources.

**The Question is**
Is it possible to show the content which is retrieved from various sources without any middle layer to manipulate data before display? Meaning the page will show the content when it receives from either of the sites at first and the page will reorder when it receives the content from other sites.

Advance thanks for your help.

Comment: Interesting. What have you tried so far?

Comment: There's no question here. Before posting, you should have done the proper research and made attempts to solve your issue yourself. Then, if you get stuck on something _specific_, come back and show us your attempt. Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi Roshan, I am working in a LMS domain, we have one LMS product for formal training given by the enterprise customers. Similarly we have another product for informal learning.  Currently we are trying to create one single common UI to show both formal and informal learning courses to the learners together.

Comment: ...that didn't clarify _anything_ about what you've tried (or what your actual question is). Please read the above links and update your question accordingly.

Comment: You need to write an Asynchronous code.

Answer (score 0):

The way i solved this issue by doing the below.

- Created one aggregate layer, which makes the request (curl) to different systems (asynchronous)
- Upon receiving response from one system (whichever comes first) have stores it in cache (memcache) and display the result in the page
- Then when the response comes form the other system, aggregate the result with the previous results which is stores in cache and refresh the page again with the aggregated data

I know this is not a good solution, but since i don't have any better option and right now handling it like this.